# Little Endian - Big Endian Problem

Tags: c++, endianness

Little Endian vs Big Endian

Big Endian = 0x31014950
Little Endian = 0x50490131

However Using this Method

```
inline unsigned int endian_swap(unsigned int& x)  
{
return ( ( (x & 0x000000FF) << 24 ) | 
         ( (x & 0x0000FF00) << 8  ) |
         ( (x & 0x00FF0000) >> 8  ) |
         ( (x & 0xFF000000) >> 24 ) );
}
```

result = 0x54110131
i spent lot of time trying lots of similar methods and even a library one like

```
unsigned long _byteswap_ulong(unsigned long value);
```

But Still no luck .. all returns same result

**EDIT**
I'm Working on Little-Endian System with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
the example as Follows

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int y = 0x31014950;
    unsigned int r = endian_swap( y );
    std::cout << r;
}
```

the example posted on Ideone.com is correct .. but it doesn't work with me

**EDIT**

```
std::cout << std::hex << r;
```

Either Ways Pals .. Hex or Not it's not getting the Right Number .. Either Visual Studio got a serious Error in it's Debugger or My Whole Machine ..
Because i Replaced the Whole Code with a More Slow Redunant code but still getting same results
BTW if it makes any difference .. i'm using Debugger to Break after the function to check the result

Comment: You are using the return value, right?  While you take `x` by reference, you never actually modify it.

Comment: `endian_swap` looks fine.  And if replacing it with a library function "returns same result", maybe your problem is somewhere outside that function.

Comment: @James made me think you're not even acting upon the value of `x`, you're doing all the swapping on the reference. Is that what you actually want?

Comment: result is printed correctly .. argument passed by refrnce and is correct .. i use the return ... nothing outside the code .. it's just the number and return

Comment: @VirusEcks: show your complete program, there's no point a bunch of people sitting around guessing what it is you've done wrong.

Comment: So when you said, "I use the return", what did you mean? The function doesn't modify `y`. The value you print out is `y`. The output of this program surely is "822167888". If you print out `r`, you'll see the endian-reversed value.

Comment: @Steve: and we need to `cout << hex`, otherwise we get decimal output

Comment: @VirusEcks: HELLO! YOU'RE PRINTING OUT `y`! Why would you think that your function, `endian_swap`, modifies `y` in any way? It doesn't.

Comment: Sorry for the Confusion .. well .. i'm not printing it out anyways .. i'm using debugger to break after the function and check the result ..

Comment: @VirusEcks: (1) does your example work as intended? (2) what is the input value, and what is the expected output value, and what is the actual output value?

Answer (score 2):

- Are you printing the result correctly?
- Does the fact that you're passing in a reference instead of a value make a difference?

Comment: will removing the refrence make a difference ? because appearantly it doesn't :/

Comment: Usually you pass in by reference if you want to change the passed-in parameter from within the function.  You don't appear to be changing `x` at all from within your function, so passing in by value makes your intention clearer (and possibly correct). :)

Comment: OK, it's not the reference thing.  Interesting problem!

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be correct.

The following program (http://ideone.com/a5TBF):

```
#include <cstdio>

inline unsigned int endian_swap(unsigned const int& x)  
{
return ( ( (x & 0x000000FF) << 24 ) | 
         ( (x & 0x0000FF00) << 8  ) |
         ( (x & 0x00FF0000) >> 8  ) |
         ( (x & 0xFF000000) >> 24 ) );
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int x = 0x12345678;
    unsigned int y = endian_swap(x);
    printf("%x %x\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

> 12345678 78563412

---

Edit:
you need `std::cout << std::hex << r`, otherwise you are printing (1) wrong variable, and (2) in decimal :-)

See this example: http://ideone.com/EPFz8

Comment: indeeed .. it works with numbers like this .. but with this hex numbers it fails ..

Comment: It *is* a hex number. :) Hence **0x** 12345678

Comment: unforunatly i'm working on Little-Endian System with visual Studio compiler

Comment: @VirusEcks: Could you please try the same example with Visual Studio?

Comment: @Vlad:  Hmmmm, OK, it's not the reference thing then.  Interesting.

Comment: @John: indeed the code is right. I assume the OP doesn't output the result properly.

Comment: @Vlad: Tried on Visual Studio, output is exactly the same.

Comment: @PigBen: Thank you! That confirms that the OP's function is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate the ampersand in front of the x in your argument specifier.  You want to pass the value.

Comment: @John: They didn't say, so impossible to know, but this doesn't even address the problem asked about.

Comment: At one point it wasn't clear whether it applied or not, but I think we've figured out now that it didn't cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you unit-tested your code?

On my platform, this passes:

```
void LittleEndianTest::testLittleEndian()
{
    unsigned int x = 0x31014950;
    unsigned int result = 
         (
             ( (x & 0x000000FF) << 24 ) + 
             ( (x & 0x0000FF00) << 8  ) +
             ( (x & 0x00FF0000) >> 8  ) +
             ( (x & 0xFF000000) >> 24 ) 
         );

    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL((unsigned int)0x50490131, result); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example in your edit is outputting y not r. The input y is, of course, not modified.

Answer (score 0):

If I run the code you posted, it gives the correct result: `endian_swap ( 0x31014950 ) == 0x50490131`.

To get the result: `endian_swap ( 0x31014950 ) == 0x54110131`, your code must be equivalent to this:

```
#define __
inline unsigned int endian_swap(unsigned int& x)  
{                  //0x31014950  ->            0x54110131
    return  ( ( (x & 0x000000FF) << 24 ) |   //  50
        __    ( (x & 0x00F0F000) << 12 ) |   //   4
        __    ( (x & 0x00FF0000) << 4  ) |   //    1  
        __    ( (x & 0x00FF0000) << 0  ) |   //     1  
        __    ( (x & 0x00FF0000) >> 8  ) |   //      01
        __    ( (x & 0xFF000000) >> 24 ) );  //        31        
}
```

Check you haven't got similar differences in your code too.

Comment: I'm Interested .. how is it 12 .. and not a multiply of 8 ?

Comment: @Roger I set the IDE to auto format code to 4 spaces indent, so use it if I want to format by hand.

Comment: @VirusEcks one hex digit (nibble) is 4 bits, not 8. Assuming the code's using f as a mask so it deals in nibbles, the 4 moves 3 nibbles or 12 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Bit operators are not useful because they operates as if the bits are arranged in order from least significant bit to most significant bit regardless of the true internal byte order.

```
void isBigEndian()
{
    void *number;
    number = (int *) new int(0x01000010);
    // 0x01000010
    //   01 00 00 10                                      Hexadecimal
    //   0    1      0    0      0    0       1    0
    //   0000 0001   0000 0000   0000 0000    0001 0000   Bit
    //   1           0           0            16          Decimal
    char *byte;
    byte = (char *)number;
    cout << static_cast<int>(*byte);//prints 16: Little Endian
}
```

You change the number above and make it return 1 when it is BigEndian.