# Reading double from binary file (byte order?)

Tags: c, io, double

I have a binary file, and I want to read a double from it.

In hex representation, I have these 8 bytes in a file (and then some more after that):

40 28 25 c8 9b 77 27 c9   40 28 98 8a 8b 80 2b d5   40 ...

This should correspond to a double value of around 10 (based on what that entry means).

I have used

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<assert.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   FILE * f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
   assert(f != NULL);
   double a;
   fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, f);
   printf("value: %f\n", a);
}
```

However, that prints 
value: -261668255698743527401808385063734961309220864.000000

So clearly, the bytes are not converted into a double correctly. What is going on?
Using ftell, I could confirm that 8 bytes are being read.

Comment: Where is the code that **wrote** these "bytes" , and was it from the same platform?

Comment: It looks like the original system wrote data out as big endian and you're trying to read it back as little endian - you just need to reverse the order of the 8 bytes.

Comment: Btw, `12.0738`for the first, `12.2979` for the second, etc if you reverse the bytes, so... reverse the bytes if reading on an LE platform. I sincerely hope if you do that *all* platforms *write* the data in BE.

Comment: Great! I was able to use fgetc with the union trick from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949144/how-to-byteswap-a-double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like integer types, floating point types are subject to platform endianness. When I run this program on a little-endian machine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t byteswap64(uint64_t input) 
{
    uint64_t output = (uint64_t) input;
    output = (output & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF) << 32 | (output & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32;
    output = (output & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF) << 16 | (output & 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000) >> 16;
    output = (output & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF) << 8  | (output & 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00) >> 8;
    return output;
}

int main() 
{
    uint64_t bytes = 0x402825c89b7727c9;
    double a = *(double*)&bytes;
    printf("%f\n", a);

    bytes = byteswap64(bytes);
    a = *(double*)&bytes;
    printf("%f\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Then the output is

```
12.073796
-261668255698743530000000000000000000000000000.000000
```

This shows that your data is stored in the file in little endian format, but your platform is big endian. So, you need to perform a byte swap after reading the value. The code above shows how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. In the end I used fgetc with the union trick from stackoverflow.com/questions/4949144/how-to-byteswap-a-double

Comment: 8 years later I end up here. One sidenote: this loses precision:

36.24139221666073 -> 36.241392

I'm still looking for the "fix" to this.

Comment: @soze no, it doesn't lose precision, you have misdiagnosed

Answer (score 2):

Endianness **is convention**. Reader and writer should agree on what endianness to use and stick to it.

You should read your number as int64, [convert endianness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105252/how-do-i-convert-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-values-in-c) and then cast to double.

Comment: Casting won't work, when you want to re-interpret the same bits. Casting will convert the (very large) integer to a very large `double`.

Comment: Pointer-casting or union-casting would work; the latter being safer in case of size mismatch, since at least you know it won't overflow on nearby variables.